# Multiple images in a table, but have vertical alignment troubles

Tags: tables, subfloats

I am sure this is a duplicate, but I could not find a question that solved my issue.  I am trying to make a figure that has 5 images in it.  The first is tall, almost twice as tall as the other 4, which are arranged as a grid.  To illustrate my issue, this is what I have so far.
[image]

As one can see in the image, the figure on the left falls right to the bottom of the table.  I tried making a macro to force the alignment to the top, but to no avail via

```
\def\imagetop#1{\vtop{\null\hbox{#1}}}
```

The code that renders my table is the following:

```
\begin{figure*}[t]
  \begin{center}
  \begin{tabular}{ccc}

  \multirow{2}{*}{
    \imagetop{\epsfxsize=1.2in
    \epsffile{eps/bands-region1.eps}}
  } & 
  \epsfxsize=1.2in
  \epsffile{eps/bands-region2.eps}
  & 
  \epsfxsize=1.2in
  \epsffile{eps/bands-region3.eps}
  \\
  & (b) & (c) \\
  &
  \epsfxsize=1.2in
  \epsffile{eps/bands-region4.eps}&
  \epsfxsize=1.2in
  \epsffile{eps/bands-region5.eps}\\
   (a) & (d) & (e) \\
  \end{tabular}
  \caption{Band diagrams... weee
  }
  \label{fig:esakibandstates}
  \end{center}
\end{figure*}
```

Any ideas on how to set the left figure at the top of the box, or even at the bottom, but above the (a), would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: `epsf` or èpsfig` are obsolete. You should use `graphicx` or its extension `adjustbox`, which defines a `valign=center` key.

Comment: @Bernard Thank you for bringing this to my attention.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`epsf.sty` has been obsolete and deprecated for more than 20 years.

Use `graphicx` for image inclusion and `subcaption` for the subfigures.

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subcaption}

\usepackage{lipsum} % for context

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1-3]

\begin{figure*}
\centering

% specifying height=... is just for emulating your pictures

\begin{tabular}{@{}cc@{}}
\subcaptionbox{}{\includegraphics[width=1.2in,height=3in]{example-image}}
&
\begin{tabular}[b]{@{}cc@{}}
\subcaptionbox{}{\includegraphics[width=1.2in,height=1.5in]{example-image}}
&
\subcaptionbox{}{\includegraphics[width=1.2in,height=1.5in]{example-image}}
\\[5ex]
\subcaptionbox{}{\includegraphics[width=1.2in,height=1.5in]{example-image}}
&
\subcaptionbox{}{\includegraphics[width=1.2in,height=1.5in]{example-image}}
\end{tabular}
\end{tabular}

\end{figure*}

\lipsum[4-20]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for bringing the epsf.sty issue to my attention.  As I have been using the same template since undergraduate school 20 years ago, it makes sense that I'm behind on the times.  The solution worked fabulously.